# a non-type template parameter cannot have type

Tags: c++, c++20

For anyone stumbling upon this question in the future, the original question was: "How to get the simplest example (Point) from this [article](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/12/02/named-arguments/) to compile with **GCC** or **CLANG**?"

- Edit 1 shows the smallest possible code that fails with CLANG but compiles with GCC (both with -std=c++2a).
- Edit 2 shows further code added, that breaks GCC as well.

The author of the article ([@BarryRevzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry)) was kind enough to comment the reason why this won't work yet, thank you Barry!

### Edit 1:

Simplified code below works with gcc 9.3.0 but not with clang 10.0.0:

```
struct Point {                                                                                                                                                                               
   int x = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                
   int y = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                
};                                                                                                                                                                                           

template <Point> // ok in C++20                                                                                                                                                              
void takes_tmpl_point();                                                                                                                                                                     

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                   
{
    // EMPTY
}
```

### Edit 2:

The original code, as per the author, won't work on GCC or CLANG as of yet due to the compilers being behind the standard a bit.  Original code below:

```
struct Point {                                                                                                                                                                               
   int x = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                
   int y = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                
};                                                                                                                                                                                           

template <Point> // ok in C++20                                                                                                                                                              
void takes_tmpl_point();                                                                                                                                                                     

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                            
   takes_tmpl_point<{.x=1, .y=2}>(); // x=1, y=2
}
```

---

This will result in the following compilation error on GCC 9.3:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘takes_tmpl_point<{1, 2}>()’
   11 |    takes_tmpl_point<{.x=1, .y=2}>(); // x=1, y=2
      |                                   ^
test.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: ‘template<Point <anonymous> > void takes_tmpl_point()’
    7 | void takes_tmpl_point();
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:11:35: error: could not convert ‘{1, 2}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Point’
   11 |    takes_tmpl_point<{.x=1, .y=2}>(); // x=1, y=2
      |                                   ^
```

---

And the following error on clang 10.0.0:

```
test.cpp:6:16: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'Point'
template <Point> // ok in C++20
               ^
test.cpp:11:21: error: expected expression
   takes_tmpl_point<{.x=1, .y=2}>(); // x=1, y=2
                    ^
2 errors generated.
```

### Compilers used:

- clang: clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
- gcc: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0

Comment: OK: does your compiler claim conformance to all of C++20?

Comment: GCC 9.3 is ok with your recent example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang just doesn't implement class types as non-type template parameters yet, see P1907 in [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

gcc does implement them but there's actually an issue here. The grammar for [*template-argument*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument) doesn't actually allow for a *braced-init-list*. This is a clear language defect (there was never a reason to have such a thing before [P1907](https://wg21.link/p1907) but now there's certainly no reason to *not* have it). This is a language bug at the moment. Nevertheless, gcc went ahead and does support a *braced-init-list* as a template argument... just not a *designated-initializer-list*.

So that blog post of mine is running ahead of the actual language by a bit... Until the language catches up, even though this is technically unsupported:

```
takes_tmpl_point<{.x=1, .y=2}>();
```

This is definitely valid:

```
takes_tmpl_point<Point{.x=1, .y=2}>();
```

Comment: Thanks Barry! So your blog talks about how the language "will" work, but compilers are slacking behind, got it! Is there any way to get this to work with the current limitations? I really like this style... and thanks for replying!

Comment: @FernandoJeronymo You can't do `takes_tmpl_point<{.y=3}>();` but you can do `takes_tmpl_point<Point{.y=3}>();` You just have to name the type.

Comment: Your naming is a bit counteridiomatic here IMO: `struct type_t { using type = T;`. In STL, _t-suffixed are usings for ::type members, not containers of those.

Comment: @bipll There are _tons_ of types in the standard library that end in `_t`: [lock tag types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag_t), [in place tag types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place), [allocator tag type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg_t), [sentinel](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/default_sentinel_t) [types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/unreachable_sentinel_t). Not to mention the integer types like `[u]intN_t`, `uintptr_t`, etc.

Comment: @Barry either scalar or empty, yes.

Comment: @bipll Yes, empty tag types. Just like mine.

Comment: @Barry not exactly. It conveys a member and is only important as such, not per se, unlike tags.