# static constexpr variables in a constexpr function

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

`static` variables are not allowed inside a `constexpr` function. Which makes sense, since `static` would introduce a state to a supposed to be pure function.

However, I don't see why we cannot have a `static constexpr` variable in a `constexpr` function. It is guaranteed to always have the same value, thus the function would remain pure.

Why would I care? Because `static` makes a difference at runtime. Consider this code:

```
#include <array>

constexpr int at(const std::array<int, 100>& v, int index)
{
    return v[index];
}

int foo1(int i) {
    static constexpr std::array<int, 100> v = { 
        5, 7, 0, 0, 5  // The rest are zero
    };
    return at(v, i);
}

constexpr int foo2(int i) {
    constexpr std::array<int, 100> v = { 
        5, 7, 0, 0, 5  // The rest are zero
    };
    return at(v, i);
}

int foo2_caller(int i) {
    return foo2(i);
}
```

Live: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/umdXgv

`foo1` has 3 asm instructions, since it stores the buffer in the static storage. While `foo2` has 15 asm instructions because it is required to allocate and initialize the buffer on each call and the compiler was not able to optimize this away.

Note that `foo1` is here only to show the flaw in `foo2`. I want to write a function that I'll be able to use at both compile and run time. That's the idea behind `foo2`. But we see it cannot be as efficient as the runtime-only `foo1`, which is disturbing.

The only meaningful related discussion I found [is this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/3gc2if/why_is_it_not_allowed_to_have_variables_of_static/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), but it does not discuss `static constexpr` specifically.

The questions are:

- Is my reasoning correct, or do I miss some problem that `static constexpr` variables might cause?
- Are there any proposals to fix this?

Comment: If you care about run time performance, why not use `foo1`?

Comment: `foo1` is here only to show the flaw in `foo2`, which I want to be available on both compile and run time.

Comment: @Mikhail At compile time there isn't going to be any assembly.  The function call will be replaced with a constant value by the compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's why the question is about runtime. I want to write a single function for both, which is the purpose of `foo2`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think the point is that the assembly generated for `foo2_caller` is inefficient.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the questions, but you can always move the array to file-scope, or to a `static constexpr` member of a struct/class. If the function this is inside of is meant to be a template, then this could be a `static constexpr` member on a class/struct template

Comment: By the way, `foo1` isn't necessarily "runtime-only"; if it's called with a constant argument, then clang and gcc are both able to optimize `foo1(4)` into a constant, which I suppose was your goal in creating `foo2`.  So `foo1` may serve your purpose after all.

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe `foo1` still is not allowed to be used in a `constexpr` context though.

Comment: @NateEldredge: You cannot do `std::array<float, foo1(4)>` but you could with `foo2`.

Comment: `static` in function does lazy initialization. I think that complicate (too much) implementation of `static constexpr`. `constexpr` already had some improvements (relaxation on constraints, ...) since C++11 to be more easy to use.

Comment: @Mikhail I've added some points to my answer regarding static storage duration. tl;dr: this would introduce persisted "state" between `constexpr` function invocations, which are meant to be stateless. It's not impossible to do, it just  that current rules complicate this and would require some large changes to allow for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No longer an issue in C++23, see [P2647R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2647r1.html).

Answer (score 14):

> Is my reasoning correct, or do I miss some problem that static constexpr variables might cause?

There are a few edge-cases that static-storage duration would have to consider when dealing with `constexpr` variables if they were allowed static-storage duration inside of a `constexpr` context.

Objects with static storage duration in a function only get constructed on *first entry into the function*. It is at this time normally that storage-backing is applied to the constants (for runtime constants). If `static constexpr` were allowed in `constexpr` context, one of two things has to happen when this is generated at compile-time:

- Executing the function at compile-time must now generate storage-backing for static constants in case it gets ODR used -- even if it is never used at runtime (which would be non-zero-overhead), or
- Executing the function at compile-time must now ephemerally create a constant that will be instantiated on each invocation, and finally given storage when a branch calls it with a runtime context (whether or not it's compile-time generated). This would violate existing rules for static storage-duration objects.

Since `constexpr` is inherently stateless throughout the context, applying a static-storage object during the `constexpr` function invocation is suddenly adding state between `constexpr` invocations -- which is a big change for the current rules of `constexpr`. Though `constexpr` functions may modify local state, the state is not globally affected.

C++20 also relaxes `constexpr` requirements to allow for destructors to be constexpr, which raises more questions such as when the destructor must execute in the above cases.

I'm not saying this isn't a *solvable problem*; it's just that the existing language facilities make solving this a little complicated without violating certain rules.

With automatic storage duration objects, this is much easier to reason about -- since the storage is coherently created and destroyed at a certain point in time.

> Are there any proposals to fix this?

None that I am aware of. There have been discussions on various google groups about rules of it, but I have not seen any proposals for this. If anyone knows of any, please link it in the comments and I will update my answer.

### Workarounds

There are a few ways you can avoid this limitation depending on what your desired API is, and what the requirements are:

1. Throw the constant into file scope, perhaps under a `detail` namespace. This makes your constant global, which may or may not work for your requirements.
2. Throw the constant into a `static` constant in a `struct`/`class`. This can be used if the data needs to be templated, and allows you to use `private` and `friend`ship to control access to this constant.
3. Make the function a `static` function on a `struct`/`class` that contains the data (if this works with your requirements).

All three of these approaches work well if the data needs to be a template, although approach 1 will only work with C++14 (C++11 did not have variable templates), whereas 2 and 3 can be used in C++11.

The cleanest solution in terms of encapsulation, in my opinion, would be the third approach of moving both the data and the acting function(s) into a `struct` or `class`. This keeps the data closely associated to the functionality. For example:

```cpp
class foo_util
{
public:
    static constexpr int foo(int i); // calls at(v, i);
private:
    static constexpr std::array<int, 100> v = { ... };
};
```

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5fAqZQ)

This will generate identical assembly to your `foo1` approach while still allowing it to be `constexpr`.

---

If throwing the function into a `class` or `struct` isn't possible for your requirements (perhaps this needs to be a free function?), then you're stuck either moving the data to file-scope (perhaps protected by a `detail` namespace convention), or by throwing it into a disjoint `struct` or `class` that handles the data. The latter approach can use access modifiers and friendship to control the data access. This solution can work, though it admittedly is not as clean:

```cpp
#include <array>

constexpr int at(const std::array<int, 100>& v, int index)
{
    return v[index];
}

constexpr int foo(int i);
namespace detail {
    class foo_holder
    {
    private:
        static constexpr std::array<int, 100> v = { 
            5, 7, 0, 0, 5  // The rest are zero
        };
        friend constexpr int ::foo(int i);
    };
} // namespace detail

constexpr int foo(int i) {
    return at(detail::foo_holder::v, i);
}
```

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_7ayPG).

This, again, produces identical assembly to `foo1` while still allowing it to be `constexpr`.

Comment: "Executing the function at compile-time must now generate storage-backing for static constants in case it gets ODR used -- even if it is never used at runtime" - why is this true? How is compile-time storage related to runtime storage?

Comment: "This would violate existing rules for static storage-duration objects." - I thought storage-duration rules were all about runtime, not about compile time.

Comment: "suddenly adding state between constexpr invocations" - I would expect that `static` is simply "ignored" on compile time.

Comment: "when the destructor must execute in the above cases" - at exactly the same point as it would execute for a global static constexpr variable.

Answer (score 5):

How's this? I stuck the array into a non-type template parameter:

```
template<std::array<int, 100> v = {5, 7, 0, 0, 5}>
constexpr int foo2(int i) {
    return at(v, i);
}
```

On [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2RePTa), `foo2`'s disassembly now matches that of your `foo1`. This currently works on GCC but not clang; it seems clang is behind the C++20 standard here (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940342/a-non-type-template-parameter-cannot-have-type) SO question).

Comment: This is interesting, I've never seen this approach before. The downside would be that this doesn't scale nicely to larger array sizes or to larger sets of constants -- since all initialization is in the template argument list. It also doesn't share across different functions well if this were needed (but then this could be moved to a class template instead or something)

Comment: Note that it requires C++20.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: The arguments could be initialized elsewhere with a function or variable if necessary. A class would make sense though if multiple functions needed the same data.